# If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)$ exists a.e and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t \,\partial x }$ is continuous, can we improve a.e existence?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity

The question is as in the title.

Let $f(t,x) : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is $C^\infty$ w.r.t $x$ for each fixed $t$ and whose derivatives w.r.t $x$ are all absolutely continuous w.r.t $t$.

Next, assume that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t \,\partial x}(t,x)$ has a version defined as a continuous function everywhere on $[0,1]^2$.

Lastly, suppose that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x)= -\Delta_x f(t,x)+  3f(x,t)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x)
\end{equation}
holds almost everywhere on $[0,1]^2$.

Then, I wonder if we can conclude that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x)$ can have a version defined as a continuous function everywhere on $[0,1]^2$. Moreover, can we even proceed further and conclude that $f(x,t)$ is $C^\infty$ "jointly" in $x$ and $t$, by iteration argument?

This seems like a subtle issue to me.. Could anyone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x)=\text{some linear combinations of derivatives of }f(x,t) \text{ w.r.t  } x$"?

Comment: Oh, I will specify it clearly.

Comment: I am trying to understand more about Serrin's paper "Regularity of solutions of the NS equations" and this question has arisen.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "can be defined everywhere continuously"?

Comment: By "smooth" do you mean "$C^1$"?

Comment: By smooth, I mean $C^\infty$.

Comment: Defined everywhere continuousy  = has a version defined as a continuous function everywhere

Comment: I am sorry for being too obscure... I edited all.